# CMOS failure MSI motherboard

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, cmos

I recently tried to get an old **MSI P965 Neo motherboard** working, but the cmos is getting cleared every time i boot the pc. I tried a new 2032 3v battery, but it still wasnt working. I can get into the BIOS and change settings, but they are cleared every time. Also, the date and time setting in the bios is flickering, it changes to random numbers.

EDIT: Also gives me a **floppy disk fail (40)**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your MoBo has soldering and data path issues.  Your CMOS issue is due to the battery not get the charge to the chipset needed to stay on.  Your Floppy disk fail is because of those bios settings where the floppy is enabled.  Since you cannot disable it, you cannot removed that error.  The gold tracers are the Data Paths.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once when I accidentally left the CMOS reset jumper in the reset position.

Also, your CMOS's default settings may enable the floppy drive, and you'll always see this on boot if you don't actually have a floppy connected (floppies are NOT plug and play and the only way to detect if one is there is to try to talk to it.)

> Also, the date and time setting in the bios is flickering, it changes to random numbers.

Though this is rather bizarre, if the above regarding a reset jumper is not true, this motherboard may be dying, or a bad capacitor is present on it.  You also may have an electrical or grounding issue with the board (you didn't screw it directly to the case, did you?)